# How to show venn diagram?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to show the following sets by Venn diagrams?

Case 1:
$$A=\{1,2,B\},B =\{3,4\}$$
Case 2:
$$A=\{1,2,3,4\}, B=\{3,4\}$$

Comment: Do you understand what a Venn diagram represents and how it works?

Comment: @Asaf..., yes.I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 1 the universe is $A=U_1=\{1,2,B\}$ and $B$ happens to be a set $\{3,4\}$. So, the "type" (whatever it means) of $B$ is the same as that of the "type" of $1$ and $2$. This means that $B\not \subset U_1$ but $B\in U_1$

In case 2 the universe is $A=U_2=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Now, the "type" of "B" is not the same as the type of $1,2,3,4$. Now, $B \subset U_2$ but $B \not \in U_2.$

The following figure is supposed to depict these two different situations:

[image]